# Interrupt operation if client connection is already closed or client has received SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, spring, api, rest

I have created an API at my backend server side code, suppose a request comes from browser and it got timeout because `identityService` took more than expected time. Since, client has already received `SocketTimeoutException` so there is no benefit to call `hrService` and `accountService` because client/browser is not going to get the response as TCP connection is already closed.

Is there a way or line of code I can write between `identityService` and `hrService` API call (and other places too) where if Client connection is already closed, my code should also stop executing next line of code.
In above example, the thread should break before `hrService` and `accountService` API call since connection is already closed.

```
////Controller class
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/detail/{employeeId}")
    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDetailResponse> employeeDetail(@PathVariable("employeeId") Long employeeId)  {
        return new ResponseEntity(employeeService.getEmployeeDetail(employeeId), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}


//// Service class 
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private IdentityService identityService;
 
    @Autowired
    private HRService hrService;
    
    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Transactional
    public EmployeeDetailResponse getEmployeeDetail(Long employeeId) {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId);

        //Call API-1 identityService to get Address and phone details
        IdentityDetail identityDetail = identityService.getIdentity(employeeId);

        //Call  API-2 hrService to get employement Details
        EmplyementDetail employementDetail = hrService.getEmployementDetail(employeeId);

        //Call API-3 accountService to get Salary details
        AccountDetail accountDetail = accountService.getAccountDetail(employeeId);

        return mergeResponses(employee,identityDetail,employementDetail,accountDetail)
    }
}
```

Appriciate your help.